# Error injecting <Object>: Unable to create or inherit binding: No @Inject or default constructor found for <Object>

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, gwt, gwt-platform

I'm new to gwt and gwtp. I'm trying to make a simple application that could connect and use EasyPost API. And when I try to run my code, it shows this error.

```
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.9.0:compile (default) @ EasyPostWebApp ---
[INFO] Compiling module easypost.EasyPostWebApp
[INFO]    Ignored 5 units with compilation errors in first pass.
[INFO] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
[ERROR] WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
[ERROR] WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2 (file:/C:/Users/Businessman/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/3.0/guice-3.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
[ERROR] WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2
[ERROR] WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
[ERROR] WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO]    Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.DesktopGinjector'
[INFO]       Rebinding com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.DesktopGinjector
[INFO]          Invoking generator com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGenerator
[INFO]             [ERROR] Error injecting easypost.client.presenters.HomePresenter$MyProxy: Unable to create or inherit binding: No @Inject or default constructor found for easypost.client.presenters.HomePresenter$MyProxy
[INFO]   Path to required node:
[INFO] 
[INFO] easypost.client.presenters.HomePresenter$MyProxy [com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.gin.AbstractPresenterModule.bindPresenter(AbstractPresenterModule.java:121)]
[INFO] 
[INFO]             [ERROR] Error injecting easypost.client.views.HomeView$Binder: Unable to create or inherit binding: No @Inject or default constructor found for easypost.client.views.HomeView$Binder
[INFO]   Path to required node:
[INFO] 
[INFO] easypost.client.views.HomeView [com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.gin.AbstractPresenterModule.bindPresenter(AbstractPresenterModule.java:120)]
[INFO]  -> easypost.client.views.HomeView$Binder [@Inject constructor of easypost.client.views.HomeView]
[INFO] 
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'gen/com/gwtplatform/mvp/client/DesktopGinjectorProvider.java'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 8: Failed to resolve 'com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.DesktopGinjector' via deferred binding
```

Here are some source codes:

/client/**EasyPostWebApp.gwt.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.9.0//EN"
        "http://gwtproject.org/doctype/2.9.0/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='easypostwebapp'>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>

  <inherits name = "com.google.gwt.uibinder.UiBinder"/>
  <inherits name="com.gwtplatform.mvp.MvpWithEntryPoint"/>

  <extend-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector.modules"
                                 value="easypost.client.views.ClientModule"/>

  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

  <set-configuration-property name="CssResource.enableGss" value="true"/>
  <set-configuration-property name="CssResource.gssDefaultInUiBinder" value="true"/>

  <!-- allow Super Dev Mode -->
  <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
</module>
```

/client/views/**HomeView.ui.xml**

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>
    <ui:style>...</ui:style>
    ...
    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <div class="{style.address-container}">
            <g:Button ui:field="createAddressButton">Create Address</g:Button>
            <div class="{style.address-box}">
                <g:HTML ui:field="serverResponse" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </g:HTMLPanel>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

/client/views/**HomeView.java**

```
public class HomeView extends ViewWithUiHandlers<HomeUiHandlers>
        implements HomePresenter.MyView {

    interface Binder extends UiBinder<HTMLPanel, HomeView> {}

    @UiField Button createAddressButton;
    @UiField HTML serverResponse;

    @Inject
    HomeView(Binder uiBinder) {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi( this ));

        createAddressButton.addClickHandler(clickEvent -> getUiHandlers().getServerResponse());
    }

    @Override
    public void setServerResponse(String serverResponse) {
        this.serverResponse.setHTML( serverResponse );
    }
```

/client/presenters/**HomePresenter.java**

```
public class HomePresenter extends Presenter<HomePresenter.MyView, HomePresenter.MyProxy>
            implements HomeHandlers {

    interface MyView extends View, HasUiHandlers<HomeUiHandlers> {
        void setServerResponse(String serverResponse);
    }

    @ProxyStandard
    @NameToken(NameTokens.HOME) // "/home"
    interface MyProxy extends Proxy<HomePresenter> {}

    private final EasyPostServiceAsync easyPostService;

    @Inject
    public HomePresenter(EventBus eventBus, HomePresenter.MyView view, HomePresenter.MyProxy proxy, EasyPostServiceAsync easyPostService) {
        super(eventBus, view, proxy, ApplicationPresenter.SLOT_MAIN);
        this.easyPostService = easyPostService;
        getView().setUiHandlers(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void getServerResponse() {
        getView().setServerResponse("Waiting for response...");

        easyPostService.helloFromServer(new AsyncCallback<>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
                getView().setServerResponse("An error occured: " + error.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                getView().setServerResponse(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

/client/gin/**HomeModule.java**

```
public class HomeModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindPresenter(HomePresenter.class, HomePresenter.MyView.class, HomeView.class,
                HomePresenter.MyProxy.class);
    }
}
```

/shared/services/**EasyPostService**

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("easyPost")
public interface EasyPostService extends RemoteService {
    String helloFromServer();
}
```

/shared/services/**EasyPostServiceAsync**

```
public interface EasyPostServiceAsync {
    void helloFromServer(AsyncCallback<String> callback);
}
```

/server/servlet/**EasyPostServiceImpl.java**

```
public class EasyPostServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements EasyPostService {
    // sample method
    @Override
    public String helloFromServer() {
        return "Hello, I am from server!";
    }
}
```

Gin module:

```
public class ClientModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new DefaultModule.Builder()
                .tokenFormatter(RouteTokenFormatter.class)
                .defaultPlace(NameTokens.HOME)
                .errorPlace(NameTokens.HOME)
                .unauthorizedPlace(NameTokens.HOME)
                .build()
        );
        install(new HomeModule());

        bind(ResourceLoader.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}
```

Am I doing this wrong or I'm just bad at this? Any help and tips are very appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I made it simpler. The RPC works fine if I just use a normal custom entry point and calling the EasyPostServiceAsync directly with `GWT.create()`. But I want to achieve this with gwtp and codesplitting.

Comment: I'd suggest you make a smaller example and narrow down the problem. It's hard for us to debug when there are so many parts. The error looks like something to do with Gin injection, rather than the EasyPost API.

Comment: @ᴇʟᴇvᴀтᴇ I already updated and made it simpler.

Comment: @JohnSmith If you boil this down to an issue with the EasyPost API/library, don't hesitate to email us (I work there) at support@easypost.com.